# convert string?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, type-conversion

I got a string like this:

```
let arrayString : String = "[[1, 123, 0], [4, 003, 21]]"
```

and I'd like to convert this string to an 2d-array of this type: `[[String]]`.

---

I've tried to use something like this lines:

```
var array : [[String]]  = arrayString as! [[String]]; // abort error
```

and also something like this:

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: ucode.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) {
        let array = json as! [[String]];
        print(array[0][0]) // prints nothing --> just ""
    }
```

---

> So I got no idea how I could solve this problem to convert:

```
"[[1, 123, 0], [4, 003, 21]]" ----> [["1", "123", "0"], ["4", "003", "21"]]
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Could be unrelated, but at some point I think converting it to 2D ints array would leads to let "003" to be "3', is it ok with you?

Comment: Hey, thanks for you're comment - No, this is one of the big problems: The string is in int format with invalid syntax like **003** instead of **3** but I need to get a string like **"003"** back, so NO. "3" is not ok in this case! `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this string is JSON, but the serializer complains about the leading zeros.

A solution is to convert the integer values to `String` by adding double quotes **before** deserializing the JSON. This can be simply achieved with regular expression

```
let arrayString = "[[1, 123, 0], [4, 003, 21]]"
let convertedArrayString = arrayString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+", with: "\"$0\"", options: .regularExpression)
let data = Data(convertedArrayString.utf8)
do {
    if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String]] {
        print(array)
    }
} catch { print(error)}
```

Comment: Thanks four your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing your code and found this error:

```
let arrayString: String = "[[1, 123, 0], [4, 003, 21]]"
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Number with leading zero around character 19. `(003)`

**This means,** your `arrayString` is not in correct json format.

> JSON string cannot have number with leading zero character.

**I removed the leading zero character from your arrayString and it worked correctly.**

```
    let arrayString : String = "[[1, 123, 0], [4, 3, 21]]"
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: arrayString.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [])
        print(json)
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but this is the BIG problem: I need the leading zeros "003" instead of "3".

Comment: This is not the solution I'd loved to get. -1