# Leading zeros cut from JSON response when using enum

Tags: swift, decodable, jsondecoder

Essentially I am using enum to account for instances where `code` is either and int or string - but it appears when the JSON value is simply an int with leading `0's` like `0039223` they get trimmed out. How can this be prevented?

Try running this code in Playgrounds:

```
let data = """
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 0039223,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

enum Code: Decodable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var code: Code
    var notes: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, code, notes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        self.notes = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .int(value)
        } else if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = .string(value)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unable to decode value for `code`")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Code.self, context)
        }
    }
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let items = try! decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)

for item in items {
    print("date: \(item.date.description)")
    print("code: \(item.code)")
    print("notes: \(item.notes)")
    print()
}
```

Comment: That's because it's an `int`, if you need the leading zeros, then treat it as a `String` instead

Comment: Where would I change that?

Comment: Preferably, where ever the JSON is been generated

Comment: I have no control over the JSON response, I can only interpret the response using Swift

Comment: *"JSON doesn't allow leading zeros in number see rfc4267 section 2.4. That is, if you have a number with leading zero, it's not proper JSON."* - [source](https://localcoder.org/check-if-a-json-value-match-a-number-with-leading-zero-and-convert-it-to-a-strin) - your JSON is invalid

Comment: Again your date formatter is very error prone. It will use whatever calendar the end user is using when parsing your date string which could end up with a completely wrong year value. Note also that if you don’t specify a calendar it might fail in some regions if there is a daylight savings transition at that day (in other words if there is no midnight). Not every day has 24 hours.

Comment: … or, worse, if the device is using a non-Gregorian calendar, that could end up with a date that is potentially centuries off. See “Working With Fixed Format Date Representations” section of the `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is invalid. You could, theoretically, clean it up, removing leading zeros in numeric occurrences of `"code"`. E.g., convert to a string, trim leading zeros (e.g., with regular expression), and then convert back to a `Data`:

```swift
guard
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?
        .replacingOccurrences(of: #""code"\s*:\s*0+(?!\b)"#, with: #""code": "#, options: .regularExpression),
    let fixedData = string.data(using: .utf8)
else { return }
```

That converts the invalid JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 0039223,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

Into:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 39223,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

And then you can decode `fixedData`.

---

Alternatively, you could make `code` a `String`, eliminating all of that custom decoder code:

```swift
struct Item: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var code: String
    var notes: String
}
```

And then have the regex quote the unquoted integers, making them parsable as strings:

```swift
guard
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?
        .replacingOccurrences(of: #""code"\s*:\s*(\d+)"#, with: #""code": "$1""#, options: .regularExpression),
    let data2 = string.data(using: .utf8)
else { return }
```

That converts:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 0039223,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

Into

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "0039223",
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

That streamlines the server response into something that doesn’t require the custom decoder.

---

But both of these are inefficient, brittle, and a little nuts. The JSON is incorrect and it should be fixed at the source, not client-side.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on [Check if a json value match a number with leading zero and convert it to a string](https://localcoder.org/check-if-a-json-value-match-a-number-with-leading-zero-and-convert-it-to-a-strin) and [rfc4267](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), JSON does not support integers with leading zeros.

So, how do you fix it?  The proper answer is to fix it at the source, what ever is generating the JSON should be updated to meet the standard requirements of the format, but, having spent my fair time with back end developers, that might be "to hard" (if you think it's "to hard" for the producers, why would you think it's going to be any easier for the consumers? )

So, loosely based on [convert string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840088/convert-string), the only choice you really have is to "fix" the json text some how.

So, if we do something like...

```
"""
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": 0039223,
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
"""
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "00\\d+", with: "\"$0\"", options: .regularExpression)
```

Well end up with...

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "0039223",
    "notes": "Take keys"
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-05-04",
    "code": "Gate: 2312231",
    "notes": "Take Box"
  }
]
```

I just want to point out something here, this is VERY naive, as any text starting with `00` will be caught by this, and, because you have date values with leading zeros, it becomes problematic, as you could end up "fixing" those values as well.

This is why I say, fixing the issue at the source is the correct way to solve this problem, as anything you do on your end is just going to cause you no end of head aches as try and compensate for every possible edge case

Oh, and this is how I parsed it, so you can still have `.int` and `.string` codes

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    var date: Date
    var code: Code
    var notes: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, code, notes
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        self.notes = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)
        
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            if let intValue = Int(value) {
                self.code = .int(intValue)
            } else {
                self.code = .string(value)
            }
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unable to decode value for `code`")
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Code.self, context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes it will always have two leading zeros and it would simply ignore if it comes with only one.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, as I started, *"this is VERY naive"* and since they have date values with leading zeros, you need to supply at least two - so, fix the issue at the source 